# CreateDirectStream with messages avro

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

In a first moment, I had to process the information from a text file:
C1_4,C2_4,C1______10,01/12/2015,30/12/2015,123456789,S,12345

Now, I need to process the same information but in format avro. How can I do it ?

Before I used this code:

```
createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc,
  Map("metadata.broker.list" -> brokerlist, "auto.offset.reset" ->    "smallest"),
  Set(topic))
```

Then I processed the messages of this way:

```
val logStream = kafkaStream.map(pair => pair._2)

logStream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
    val new_rdd = rdd.map(f = line => {

      val ent = line.split(Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER)(0)
      val cenReg = line.split(Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER)(1)
      .......

      .......
    })
  })
```

---

Now I was trying do something of this way:

```
  createDirectStream[Object, Object, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder](ssc,
  Map("metadata.broker.list" -> brokerlist, "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest"),
  Set(topic))


Also I have to use a SchemaRegistry that the client give me.


How can I process the messages avro ?
```

Comment: Some idea, please ?